# Remove String caption on a Json Format

Tags: php, json

i do the json encode, pfb my code.

```
$encoded = json_encode($arr);
var_dump($encoded);
```

result is like below.

```
string(16007) "[{"NO":0,"GPSSTATE":"Valid Location","GPS":1,"TIME":1464666561,"USERNAME":"mostniaga","TIME_FORMAT":"31-May-2016 10:49:21","LICENSE":"B 2291 SFS","TERMINAL":"358899052470419","OWNERTELP":" ","OWNERNAME":" ","TYPE":"IDTRACK","LONGITUDE":106.8083,"LATITUDE":-6.267059,"ADDRESS":"Pangeran Antasari-JAKARTA SELATAN (KOTA),DKI JAKARTA","SPEED":0,"DIRECTION":116,"MILEAGE":14055655,"ALARMSTATE":0,"CARSTATE":0,"ICONID":"0","GSM":"082212133958","STATUS":"Stop And Parking","STATUS_ENGINE":"ENGINE OFF","EXP_DATE":"Sep 7 2016 12:00:00:000AM","STATUS_EXP":"active","VEHICLE_STATE":" ","VEHICLE_TYPE":"Minibus"},
{"NO":1,"GPSSTATE":"Valid Location","GPS":1,"TIME":1464666653,"USERNAME":"mostniaga","TIME_FORMAT":"31-May-2016 10:50:53","LICENSE":"F 1540 KN","TERMINAL":"358899052465716","OWNERTELP":" ","OWNERNAME":" ","TYPE":"IDTRACK","LONGITUDE":106.8626,"LATITUDE":-6.480568,"ADDRESS":"Jagorawi-BOGOR,JAWA BARAT","SPEED":0,"DIRECTION":357,"MILEAGE":16698669,"ALARMSTATE":0,"CARSTATE":0,"ICONID":"0","GSM":"082212133959","STATUS":"Stop And Parking","STATUS_ENGINE":"ENGINE OFF","EXP_DATE":"Sep 7 2016 12:00:00:000AM","STATUS_EXP":"active","VEHICLE_STATE":" ","VEHICLE_TYPE":"Minibus"}]"
```

i want to remove this string caption below, how to do that ?

```
string(16007) "
```

Comment: first `json_encode` does not have TRUE as a parameter. You can use regular expression or json_decode unset and json_encode.

Comment: then don't use `var_dump`, just use `echo`

Comment: @FrayneKonok i've been remove the true, but string still exist, can you refer me a url or sample for json_decode unset

Comment: @RodrigoDuterte thanks it work

Comment: Your `json_encode` must return you a string, to see the string just `echo` it, To see the type use `var_dump`.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to output the json string you should probably just use `echo $encoded`, for instance if you have an ajax call, you could echo the answer out.

However, there is a PHP command oftern overlooked that will remove all clutter from var_dump and make it copy-pastable, great for arrays and such and that is  `var_export($encoded)`